# Angular 2 Interfaces vs Generics - Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm familiar with Interfaces from using AS3, but Generics… not so much.

Can someone explain why I'd use a generic vs implementing an interface? I don't understand the difference in utility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the [official typescript docs on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)?

Comment: Thanks. I get it. 
No more questions I can answer for myself. :)